# Debug webpage memory and CPU usage, ideally on mobile safari?

Tags: debugging, remote-debugging

I have a web page which has a bug that Ive only seen on one device with mobile safari. My hunch is that its a CPU / memory issue, how can I debug this?

In perfect world I could remotely debug this on the actual device (an iPhone 5s), however any sort of memory / CPU debugging would be helpful.